# Checkov in windows

Tags: terraform, devops, checkov

Can checkov-satic code analysis for infrastructure as a tool can be installed or not?

I checked the documentation. It has mentioned the steps for Unix, but not for windows

Comment: Can you link to the tool? I've not heard of it before and you don't have a tag for it either.

Comment: https://www.checkov.io/

Comment: python is a pre-requisite, to get checkov its just "pip3 install checkov"

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to install it on windows or use the docker packing to gain similar results.

If you have any issue, feel free to reach out at https://slack.bridgecrew.io/

Barak, The creator of checkov